# How to add a class to an element when enters view

Tags: jquery, scroll, addclass, scrolltop

I am looking to add a class to a div when i scroll to the top of it and it comes just into view on the screen. 
I have been able to do this when the whole height of the div is in view but not as i scroll and hit the top of it, perhaps with an offset ability?
Very new to this so any help would be massively appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3LghLrye/)**

```
$('div').animate({top:'500px'},1000);
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if(!$('div').hasClass('red') && $('div').offset().top<=$(window).height()+$(document).scrollTop()){
        $('div').addClass('red');
    }
});
```